# Number of units of $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

Let $n\mathbb{Z} = \{nk\::\:k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. Find the number of units of $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$.

I tried this problem by using the fact that since $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$ so number of units in  $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ are $11$ and $12$ respectively. But in book its answer is $10$ and $4$ respectively given by $\phi(n)$.

Plz resolve this issue.

Comment: $ℤ/11ℤ$ is a ring with a multiplicative identity $[1]_{11ℤ}$ and $11$ is the number of *all* elements in $ℤ/11ℤ$. The *units* of $ℤ/11ℤ$ are the elements in it which are invertible with respect to multiplication. For example, $[0]_{11ℤ}$ is not multiplicatively invertible.

Comment: Ok thanks so much. I havn't done rings as yet

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$It is a standard fact that a class $[a] \in \Z/ n / \Z$ is a unit iff $\gcd(a, n) = 1$. So the number of units is given by the Euler function $\varphi(n)$.

In fact we have $\varphi(11) = 10$, as all numbers $1, 2, \dots, 10$ are coprime to $11$. (More generally, if $p$ is prime we have $\varphi(p) = p-1$.)

Whereas $\varphi(10) = 4$, as $1, 3, 7, 9$ are the number in $\{ 0, 1, \dots 9 \}$ that are coprime to $10$.

---

The proof of my first statement is the following. $[a] \in \Z/ n / \Z$ is a unit iff there is $b$ such that $[a] [b] = [1]$ iff there are $b, k$ such that $a b = 1 + n k$ iff there are $b, k$ such that $a b - n k = 1$ [iff $\gcd (a, n) = 1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).